# Interactive .NET Charting tools?

Tags: .net, charts

We are looking to implement some complex charting graphs for a new application we are building.  Some of the charts are scatter graphs that sometimes have a high clustering of data in specfic areas.  Is there a charting tool that is similar to Google Maps that gives you a high level view, and then if there is too much clustering, a user can zoom in on a specific area to get a more detailed look and the points start spreading out?  Free or otherwise isn't an issue.

Comment: As owner of Gigasoft, if researching complex charting for engineering, finance; include [Gigasoft .Net Charting](http://www.gigasoft.com) in your search results. Our annotation features fit nicely in this topic. v8 is next generation with Direct2D, 3D, Directx11. Link includes a 7 Meg demo download in WinForm, Wpf, and native c++ variations for comparison.  The demo quickly demonstrates a large feature set with simple to use annotations that allows for complex chart creation.

Comment: Take a look at Nevron Chart for .NET (http://www.nevron.com). The control supports LOD point clustering, line sampling, zooming, scrolling, panning etc. I work for Nevron.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [Microsoft Chart Controls for .Net 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) they also include nice demo application where you can browse the chart samples and see how it works with code samples.

These Chart Controls are by default included in .Net 4.0 so no separate installation is needed.

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/chart/step3.png))</sub>

Comment: do u know if it is possible to do delete data points off the chart (and not the source data) by clicking on it?

Comment: Finding this as a the result of a search, I'd like to update this response by mentioning that these tools are now included in .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Microsoft Chart Controls ; They have interactivity and AJAX that you can use to zoom in and out.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. You can either go with the Microsoft chart controls like others have mentioned or you could checkout the following.

[1. http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/chart.aspx](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/chart.aspx)

[2. http://www.dundas.com/Products/Chart/NET/index.aspx](http://www.dundas.com/Products/Chart/NET/index.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/) has some great charting tools depending on your app. (ASP.NET, Winforms, WPF, Silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Dundas charts:

http://www.dundas.com/

For maps you have virual earth

http://www.bing.com/maps/

Answer (score 0):

Try [NPlot](http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/) which is a free library. Used it in a stock-related application and is easy to use.